# Geocoding tools in node.js

Tags: node.js, geocoding, geo

I am looking for node.js library for manipulating geo-spatial data. I have a large set of geo tagged data in database.

The desired functionalities include:

1. GeoCoding and reverse Geocoding
2. Find nearby items
3. Find items within a geological bound

Just like a node equivalent to the GeoCoder gem in RoR.

Answer (score 2):

Having found this question while trying to answer it myself, I'll update this.

The [geocoder](https://github.com/wyattdanger/geocoder) library recommended above was last updated in 2014 doesn't seem to deal with Promises. [node-geocoder](https://github.com/nchaulet/node-geocoder) is being actively maintained and it's promise based api lets you do stuff like this if you are using Babel/ES7:

```
const NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
let geocoder = NodeGeocoder()
let assert = require('assert');

describe('geocoder#geocode()', () => {

    it('geocodes things', async () => {
      let result = await geocoder.geocode("Ottawa, Canada")
      assert.equal(45.4215296, result[0].latitude)
    })

})
```

I do find that node-geocoder gives a subset of the result it gets from Google/whomever, where Ruby's geocoder project seems to give the entire response.

```
//result returned from geocoder.geocode:
[ { formattedAddress: 'Ottawa, ON, Canada',
    latitude: 45.4215296,
    longitude: -75.69719309999999,
    extra: 
     { googlePlaceId: 'ChIJrxNRX7IFzkwR7RXdMeFRaoo',
       confidence: 0.5,
       premise: null,
       subpremise: null,
       neighborhood: null,
       establishment: null },
    administrativeLevels: 
     { level2long: 'Ottawa Division',
       level2short: 'Ottawa Division',
       level1long: 'Ontario',
       level1short: 'ON' },
    city: 'Ottawa',
    country: 'Canada',
    countryCode: 'CA',
    provider: 'google' } ]
```

Finding data based on it's lat/lng is going to be something the database takes care of. I've been using [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com) and they have a function `WITHIN_RECTANGLE` which is the perfect complement to the `map.getBounds()` you have with [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds)/[Mapbox-gl-js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#getBounds). Here is an example:

```
export async function locationsWithinBounds(swLat, swLng, neLat, neLng) {
  let query = aqlQuery`
    RETURN WITHIN_RECTANGLE(vertices, ${swLat}, ${swLng}, ${neLat}, ${neLng})
  `
  let results = await db.query(query)
  let allResults = await results.all()
  return allResults[0]
}
```

If you explore their other [geo functions](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/Geo.html) you will find things like `NEAR` and `IS_IN_POLYGON`.
If you need geo functions for usage in the browser you should be looking at [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/).

Comment: Is "node-geocoder" a free library?

Answer (score 0):

For the GeoCoding and reverse part, you can use https://github.com/wyattdanger/geocoder

```
npm install geocoder
```

For the find part, the best way is to use your database system, if it's support geo operations.

If not, maybe duplicate your database into another one(with geo operation)? if you need to work on gigabyte of data, not very...easy to load everything in memory, database exist for that :).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your applications are, some form of Geohashing may help if you're indexing things that don't come from a straight Geocoding / rev-Geocoding API.

One type of Geohash is [S2 from Google](http://s2geometry.io), which can index regions with the precision of something smaller to a fingertip to a face of the Earth with a 64-bit integer.

Here's an example of finding if something is in a boundary with the [Node S2 Library](https://github.com/radarlabs/s2) with O(1) runtime on retrieval. In this case, it's checking if someone is in Williamsburg, Brooklyn:

```
const s2 = require('@radarlabs/s2');

const williamsburgLongLats = [
  [-73.95841598510742, 40.72423412682422],
  [-73.96957397460938, 40.71226430831242],
  [-73.9683723449707, 40.70497727808752],
  [-73.96184921264648, 40.69951148213175],
  [-73.95923137664795, 40.70852329864894],
  [-73.94775152206421, 40.70391994183744],
  [-73.94163608551025, 40.71145106322093],
  [-73.94335269927979, 40.71834706657437],
  [-73.9469575881958, 40.719778223045275],
  [-73.94970417022705, 40.722217623379684],
  [-73.95056247711182, 40.721892375167045],
  [-73.95193576812744, 40.72335597960796],
  [-73.95425319671631, 40.72312830991985],
];

const lls = williamsburgLongLats.map((lnglat) => {
  const [lng, lat] = lnglat;
  return new s2.LatLng(lat, lng);
});

const s2Level = 14; // ~0.32 km^2
const neighborhoodS2Cells =
  new Set(s2.RegionCoverer.getCoveringTokens(
    lls,
    { min: s2Level, max: s2Level }
  ));

const user1LongLat = [-73.95429611206055, 40.71369559554873]; // in williamsburg
const user2LongLat = [-73.9266586303711, 40.71616774648679];  // not in williamsburg

const user1S2 = new s2.CellId(new s2.LatLng(user1LongLat[1], user1LongLat[0])).parent(14); // level 14 to ensure 1:1 mapping to cover
const user2S2 = new s2.CellId(new s2.LatLng(user2LongLat[1], user2LongLat[0])).parent(14); // level 14 to ensure 1:1 mapping to cover

console.log(neighborhoodS2Cells.has(user1S2.token())); // true - O(1)
console.log(neighborhoodS2Cells.has(user2S2.token())); // false - O(1)
```